# Detect horizontal scrolling in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, scroll, eclipse-plugin

I've written an [Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/donkirkby/live-py-plugin) that adds a second [`SourceViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2Fsource%2FSourceViewer.html) beside the standard Python editor window. I can detect when either window is scrolled vertically as follows:

```
displayViewer = new SourceViewer(liveDisplay, ruler, styles);
displayViewer.addViewportListener(new IViewportListener() {
    @Override
    public void viewportChanged(int verticalOffset) {
        // respond to scroll event
    }
});
```

Is there any equivalent to detect horizontal scrolling? I tried adding a control listener, but that doesn't detect scroll events.